# Visual Studio Code - Exclude subdirectories from NPM Script Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

My workspace directory contains `package.json` with some scripts and two subdirectories containing few other `package.json` files that I want to exclude from Script Explorer. Call them `adir`, `bdir`.

But any string I put in `npm.exclude` seems to simply reorder the visible entries in Script Explorer.

I tried first to exclude only one directory with `"adir"`, `"adir/**/*"` but the directory is always present. Better results with `"**/*"` that excludes all subdirectories but leaves in Script Explorer only the first script from the workplace `package.json` file.

Worse if I try to exclude both subdirectories using `"{adir,bdir}/**/*"` or `"[ab]dir/**/*"` that seems to do nothing.

Also changing `npm.exclude` to an array of strings do nothing.

I run latest VSC on Windows 10 64 bits.

What I'm missing?

Thanks!
mario

Comment: Tried doing this: `**/adir`?

Comment: Yes, no effect. `adir` scripts still present. But `"**/adir/**"` seems to work!

Comment: I tried it and it worked.

Comment: Almost there (thanks Harry for the hint!). `"**/{adir,bdir}/**"` excludes both directories except for `bdir/package.json` scripts.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with npm.exclude not working as expected https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114562